# Embedded Spotify Playlists don't work on mobile devices

Tags: spotify, playlist

I have playlists embedded in my site.

When I click on the playlist from a browser on a desktop/laptop, it spawns the Spotify app and begins playing the playlist. When I do this from a mobile browser, it spawns Spotify but doesn't load the playlist, just the song you clicked on. The queue becomes the album containing the song you click on. The playlist doesn't appear to get loaded. I thought I had tested this before and it had worked.

Here's the embed code:

```
<iframe 
  src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:brucemciccone:playlist:6gabGbGL7ckAE3wXkt62AB" 
  width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which mobile device you're using, but I'm fairly certain this has worked as you describe on iOS from the outset. Less certain about Android, but it's probably the same.

Comment: I tested on an iPhone and an Ipad - same result. Is there anyone from Spotify I can ask about this?

Comment: Yes, me. As I implied, the Play Button isn't fully supported on mobile.